# Extracting function calls with parameters

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a translation function and wanted to list all translations with namespace with regex.

The best thing i came up with so far is:

`translate[\s]*\((?|'([^']*?(?:\\'|)[^']*?)'|"([^"]*?(?:\\"|)[^"]*?)")(?:|[, ]*(?:'|")(.*?)(?:"|'))\)`

However, part `([^']*?(?:\\'|)[^']*?)` is too hard for my regEx skills. Any help?

Can't find any way to match exclude sequence `\'`.

```
translate('hello what\'s wrong');
translate('hello what\'s wrong');
translate('hello what\'s wrong');
translate("hello what's w: )rong");
translate("hello whats wrong");
translate('hello what\'s wrong');

translate('hello what\'s wrong', 'namespace');
translate('hell\'o what\'s wro\'ng', 'namespace');
translate("hello what\"s \" s\" wrong", 'namespace');
translate('hell(o) (wh)at\'s wrong', "namespace");
translate("hello what's wrong", "namespace");

translate  ('hello what\'s wrong');
translate("hel
lo what's wrong");

translate('hello what\'s wrong', 'namespace');
translate("hello wh
at's wrong", 'namespace');
translate('hello what\'s wrong', "namespace");
translate("hello what's wrong", "namespace");

translate[\s]*\((?|(?:')([^']*?(?:\\'|)[^']*?)(?:')|(?:")([^"]*?(?:\\"|)[^"]*?)(?:"))(?:|[, ]*(?:'|")(.*?)(?:"|'))\)
```

For easier debug what's not working https://regex101.com/r/8Jzso3/4

PS: I may have overcomplicated it already with all those groups.

Comment: What language/library/tool are you using?

Comment: @melpomene PHP's `preg_match`

Comment: `translate('asdf',translate('asdf'),'as\l\\\\\'')`

Comment: `translate('as\l\\\\\'')` `translate('as\l\\\\\\'')` `translate('as\l\\\\\\\'')`

Comment: You have to account for nesting, and you can never decode _anything escaped_ without decoding the escaped escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all the test strings, I think all you need to do is to `*` repeat the group between the starting `'` and the ending `'`, or the starting `"` and the ending `"` (the groups which match non-escaped quotes up to a single escaped `\'` or `\"`). Turn the repeated group into a non-capturing group, and use another group around the repeated one to capture everything between the outer quotes in the argument string.

You can also simplify `translate[\s]*` to `translate\s*`, because there's only a single character in that character set.

```
translate\s*\((?|'((?:[^']*?(?:\\')[^']*?)*)'|"((?:[^"]*?(?:\\"|)[^"]*?)*)")(?:|[, ]*(?:'|")(.*?)(?:"|'))\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/8Jzso3/6

Comment: Thx, but it won't do. Look at match9, it does not extract string properly
My main problem is to skip `'` and include `\'`